# If $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} {g(x)} = 0$, is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} {f(x)} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, contest-math

Is it true that

> Show $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} {g(x)} = 0 \implies \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} {f(x)} = 0$?

This question in a variant came up on this year's Putnam, and it interested me. My thought process was that it should be true by contradiction, if $f(x)$ was some constant in the limit, then the quotient would have to explode in the limit. Is this logic correct?

Comment: proof by contradiction boom its true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lim F(x)$ and $\lim G(x)$ both exist, then so does $\lim(F(x)G(x))$, and it's equal to the product of the two limits. Now let $F(x)=f(x)/g(x)$ and $G(x)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

For $ x$ close to $ 0^+$, which means for $x\in (0,\eta)$ for some $\eta>0$, we have

$$|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|<1$$
or

$$-|g(x)|<f(x)<|g(x)|$$
thus

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=0$$
(squeeze).